# Timestamp not saving on the right current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The code below saves a Timestamp into `session_end`. Please don't mind the attribute name called `session_end`, its supposed to be `signout_time`

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    clear_all_sessions current_user.id
    save_signout_time(current_user.id)
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def save_signout_time(id)
    SignupHistory.where(member_id: id)[0].update(session_end: Time.now)
  end
end
```

I don't seems to get what am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is not happening? Also `SignupHistory.where(member_id: id)[0]` could be `SignupHistory.find_by_member_id(id)`

Comment: @engineersmnky good catch. Additionally you could use `SignupHistory.find_by(member_id: id)`

Comment: Given your comments below a better understanding of schema would be a useful addition to this post. (e.g. adding the `User` and `SignupHistory` models or at least the schema declarations)

Comment: What is a `SignupHistory`? Why do you load all and then use the first? Are there multiple `SignupHistories` per user? Do you really update the first history record? Or the latest? Or the first without a `session_end` set? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: @spickermann Am only trying to update a table with timestamp upon user signing out of the application.

Comment: I think the problem is because I have many records with the same ID, and my solution picking the first [0] will update the first record.

Comment: Maybe sorting and picking the last record will work

Comment: Since you have multiple SignupHistories per user, the only problem is finding the right record to update. I think if you pick the recent one or the record that has `session_end` value empty, would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

After running `clear_all_sessions`, you probably also invalidated the current session. Thus, after calling the method, your `current_user` method will probably return the details of some anonymous user.

That is, your two calls to `current_user` will likely return different users. As a workaround, try to save the value of `current_user.id` in a variable on your `destroy` method first and use only this variable:

```
def destroy
  id = current_user.id

  clear_all_sessions id
  save_signout_time(id)
  reset_session
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: OP If this is the case please also look into your `current_user` methodology as it should never return "some anonymous user".

Comment: Still didnt work. It updates the first data in the database and not the correct signed out current user. If you login 7 time and sign out 7 times, the current session is what should be updated. In my case it updates only the data of your first sign in which is not current user.

Comment: So if you have multiple `SignupHistory` objects / database rows per user, you have to specifically identify the one you want to update. Just selecting the first one will likely not match your current session.

Comment: @HolgerJust Thats what I thought

Comment: I think the problem is because I have many records with the same ID, and my solution picking the first [0] will update the first record.